# iterating "This" properties in a method of a class C#

Tags: c#, class, methods, instance

I been search but have no luck with this, im trying to call a method in a class from a table in a DB this method call another that find a entry and fill the object however i want to pass this object to my instance of the class

```
 public class ProductCategory
    {
        public int ProductCategoryID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Guid rowguid { get; set; }

        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }


        public void FindItem<T1>(T1 id)
        {
            try
            {

                var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType());
                obj = Dal.ObjFind(obj, id); //this fill the object 
                //i want something like
                foreach properties in obj
                this.propertie = obj.propertie


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

        }

    }
```

in a way that i can call that method like

```
ProductCategory test = new ProductCategory();
test.Find(1);
```

and after that my object is loaded, i would really appreciate any help with this and sorry for the bad English or if i not explain clearly

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found a way to achieve as Pac0 say with reflection you can do this

```
public  void FindItem<T1>(T1 id)
        {
            try
            {

                var obj = this;
                // fill the object with the DB data
                obj = Dal.ObjFind(new Production.ProductCategory(), id);

                PropertyDescriptorCollection PropertyObj = 
                 TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
                //iterating the properties in the instance of the class
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in PropertyObj)
                {
                    //Get the value for each properties in the filled Obj
                    //and set that value for each properites in "this"
                    prop.SetValue (this,prop.GetValue(obj));
                }



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

        }
```

in that way you can call your instalce like "test.FindItem(1)" and the object will be load, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for giving feedback and your own working solution ! By the way, you can mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To get information at runtime about the some class durig runtime is called *reflection** (this term should help you in your searches)

To get all the properties of a Type, you can use [Type.GetProperties()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx) .

have a look at [GetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek55ae84(v=vs.110).aspx) as well.

With this, you should be able to achieve what you want.

However, I'm not convinced it's the simplest way to go. Probably someone will come up with a better way to solve your underlying issue.

Comment: i all ready working with reflection however this case is different, because i want to alter the instance itself through a method, i can make the assignation test=test.Find(1) but thats its what i wan avoid

Comment: @V-mos you can perfectly "alter the instance itself" with reflection, so I am not sure if I understand your comment properly.

Comment: After some thoughts, I would rather use some interface, something like `ICopyable<T>` with a method returning a copy of the object like `public T CreateCopy(T original)`, and implement it for all the classes where you need to get a copy from the objects, or use a base class and reflection to create only one implementation and make all db classes inherit from that baseclass.